# Android: Is it possible to get the Provider name from the account object or vice-versa

Tags: android, email, accountmanager

I got the account object using below code

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
//Log.d("Account", "get last sync time " + account.name);
if(account.name.equalsIgnoreCase("name@company.com"))
mAccount = account;
}
```

But now i need the app's package name that has configured this account (For eg. If this account has been configured by Native Email i need the package name : "com.android.email").  OR

Is it possible to get the account object from the PackageInfo object?

Comment: Please check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: i could understand the authority name will be with package name follwed by ".provider" but my problem is i couldnt get the package name using the account object